# How can I have 2 exchange accounts on a single profile in Outlook 2007?

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2007

I'm trying to configure Outlook 2007 for a user so that he would be able to have two mailboxes coming from 2 accounts, on 2 different Exchange servers, in a single Outlook 2007 window.
Until now, we were using profiles, but it's not really convenient to follow the two accounts at same time.

I have seen [several solutions explained](https://serverfault.com/questions/40010/how-to-manage-multiple-email-accounts-on-outlook-exchange-2007), but they don't seem to work for two Exchange accounts.

Is it possible to make such thing without separate profiles? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Outlook 2007 it's only possible to have one Exchange account per Outlook profile. The only way to add another account for an Exchange mailbox is to add it as a POP account.

That being said, we've had to do this for a small number of our customers and it's not pretty. As inconvenient as it may be, my recommendation is to use multiple Outlook profiles, one for each Exchange account.

Comment: Well, that's a pity, but thanks for the answer. Would you know if this is different for Outlook 2010, by chance?

Comment: It is. With Outlook 2010 you can have multiple Exchange accounts in the same Outlook profile.

Comment: Great, so migrating to the newer version could be a solution. Is it only valid for the mail, or tasks and calendar as well?

Comment: An Exchange account encompasses the entire Exchange mailbox, so yes it would encompass all folders in the mailbox, including Calendar, Contacts, Tasks, etc..

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the story of what exactly are you trying to achieve and why, but I believe synchronization tool such as [CB Exchange
Server Sync](https://www.connecting-software.com/cb-exchange-server-sync/)  can help. You can synchronize multiple Exchange accounts even across different domains (emails, calendars, notes, contacts, folders, tasks). You can also set it for one directional sync. or both ways.

Comment: ...and it can synchronize Exchange accounts running on all of these: Exchange 2010, 2013, 2016 and 365